# Disable postback at click of LinkButton in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

I am using UpdatePanel in an asp.net page. The panel has several controls. I want to disable postback call when one of the LinkButton Control inside the UpdatePanel is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnClientClick="return false;"` to the Button.

Or if you do want to do a client side operation:

```
OnClientClick="return myFunction()"
```

Then in `myFunction` return a boolean.

Comment: but I would like to run server side code when the link button is clicked

Comment: You want to disable PostBack AND run server code. You do realize that a PostBack is the trigger to execute server code.

Comment: I mean I do not want the page to reload. I am using LinkButton to download Excel and since the LinkButton  control is in UpdatePanel, the page reloads and the download does not happen. I dont want the page to reload

Comment: Ah... Then you have to add the Button as an Async PostBack trigger.

Comment: The link button is part of itemTemplate in GridView. where should I insert the trigger tag

Comment: I am using Telerik RadGrid and not GridView. The Telerik RadGrid is part of UpdatePanel. I tried registering the linkbutton control for postback but I am unable to figure out how to call the function which will do the binding